# Scraping text from 3 connected dropdown menus

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, web-scraping

I want to collect the data of three connected dropdown menus on a website.
It's about cars so the first is the brand, the second the model and the third is the motor type.
It's in a tree like structure.

An example: First you choose BMW then the second dropdown menu lets you choose a model lets say we take the X6. The third menu will now show us all possible motor configurations for **this** car. I want to scrape the whole "treelike" structure but I cant figure out how.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    import xlsxwriter
    from time import sleep

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    url =
    driver.get(url)
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Titel.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    i=1
    q=37
    w=1
    x=0
    p=1


    while 0==0:
        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="typeSelectionField_1"]'))
        select2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="typeSelectionField_2"]'))
        select3 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="typeSelectionField_3"]'))
    z1=len(select.options)
        if q>=z1:
            break
        else:
            select.select_by_index(q)

            z2=len(select2.options)
            if w>=z2:
                w=1
                q=q+1

                select.select_by_index(q)
                sleep(0.1)
                select2.select_by_index(1)
                sleep(0.1)
                select3.select_by_index(1)
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="access_buttons"]/div/button[1]').click()

            else:
                select2.select_by_index(w)

                z3=len(select3.options)
                if i<z3:
                    select3.select_by_index(i)

                    Typenbezeichnung = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_kbanr"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/label').text
                    Motor = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_kbanr"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/label').text
                    Baujahr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_kbanr"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/label').text
                    worksheet.write('A%d'%p, Typenbezeichnung)
                    worksheet.write('B%d'%p, Motor)
                    worksheet.write('C%d'%p, Baujahr)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="access_buttons"]/div/button[1]').click()
                    p = p+1
                elif i>z3-1:
                    w=w+1
                    i=1
                    x=x+1
                    select.select_by_index(q)
                    sleep(0.1)
                    select2.select_by_index(1)
                    sleep(0.1)
                    select3.select_by_index(1)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="access_buttons"]/div/button[1]').click()
    workbook.close()
`
```

This is the code. It seems to work at first, but it becomes slower over time and then throws an error, if it needs to much time to chose the next index.
I tried some things (the sleep(0.1) for example), but I can not really fix it.

Comment: give a link to the site you're scraping and post code which you have tried

Comment: https://www.kfzteile24.de/ This is the Website. I did not really code anything. I tried to do it with octoparse and I tried to understand the websitecode... I'm not that good at coding and have not done it in a year...

Comment: despite you're good or not at it, start coding=) you can start with [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) module.

Comment: I will try, but I still have no idea about how to solve my problem...

Comment: ok, I'll give you a start. In general firstly you have to open needed page with python and transform it to string for further transforming it to `BeautifulSoup` object. Then you'll be able to apply all module's methods for parsing. All these steps are googled well, so you most probably won't have problems with searching=)

Comment: I will reinstall my Ubuntu partition for this...but before I get into coding a second time, do you know that what I want is possible?

Comment: I inspected that page a while, all elements in dropboxes are presented in the markup. You can check it yourself by clicking Ctrl+Shift+I and inspecting page.

Comment: There is a JavaScript execution though, so some page elements will appear _after_ you open page with some libraries that make requests to the page.
But for this case there are solutions as well=)

Comment: So you say it is possible...well I will give it a try

Comment: Yep, my bad, they are not loaded from the start, only after clicks, that time I clicked all of them=)
But anyway, there is an option to get those values - `selenium` module. It  simulated browser work and user clicks and whatever stuff that happens in browser.

Comment: I should still start the way you supposed or shouldn't I?

Comment: In this case you can fully complete your task with `selenium`, no need in using `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Thank you, I will get into selenium :) Maybe I will continue learing to code....but first I have to solve this :)

Comment: continue learning in any case=) never know when it will be useful) good luck

Comment: I think I did it :) It runs but it will need some hours...I will write if it runs through with no bugs. :) Thank you a 1000000 times for your help!! If it works, do you want the code?

Comment: well, in case of success you can outline the code as an answer here, maybe other people could use it as an example=)

Comment: I have found a bug and I do not know how to fix it... could you help me? or give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sleep(0.1)` is too little value - it's 0.1 seconds, don't know for sure, but maybe `FirefoxDriver` doesn't load contents of the page try extending `sleep` to 1-2 second or a little more.

Comment: I tried around a bit and 0.5 works perfectly for me :) I am finished and will post the code as an answer today evening so everybody can use it :)